# How do you pronounce this phrase, "as for me"?

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce this phrase, "as for me"?:

> 1. /æz fɔr mi/
> 2. /æz fər mi/
> 3. /əz fɔr mi/
> 4. /əz fər mi/

Comment: If this is not answerable by looking at the dictionary pronunciations then it becomes primarily opinion based.

Comment: Highly dependent on context.

Comment: @Jim Poppycock! Shame on the upvoter of your comment. Pronouncing dictionaries cannot cover the pronunciations of function words, or in fact any words when appearing in connected speech. But that does not make their pronunciation not rule bound. That's a bit like saying that if you can't find out how to treat a rare diease in an undergraduate medical textbook, then its treatent is just a matter of opinion. Does that not sound ridiculous to you???

Comment: @Araucaria - I pronounce those three words just as the dictionaries say they are pronounced.  The OP gives no context for them that might influence differently. And beyond that different dialects may say them differently but It then becomes opinion-based as to who is correct. Or rather, they’re all correct- each in their own context.

Comment: @Jim If you pronounce those as in the dictionary in the string *As for me* then you don' t speak standard English. Those pronunciations are for citation forms, which we use when such words are stressed or stranded. In any other environment in connected speech, we use so -called weak forms. This is not an optional feature of English. It is a systematic feature relating to the organisation of information and its relationship to stress. It is a scientically observable fact, and in no way can be considered a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to which pronunciations to use from the dictionary.

The vowel /ə/ appears in the weak forms of the words *as* and *for*; these are used when the words are unstressed.

Generally, you would put stress on *as* and *me* in the phrase *as for me*. This means that your third pronunciation is really wrong, because it uses the weak form of the word *as* and not *for*, while your second pronunciation is probably the most likely one. Your first pronunciation doesn't reduce *for*, but this would not be uncommon in formal speech. Your fourth pronunciation only has stress on *me*, but that's also possible, depending on the surrounding words, the context, and whether you're speaking quickly.